# Update email object in SSIS is not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created one SSIS in which I'm sending emails using script task. It is working fine but the problem is now I want to edit the email template in script task. When I have edit the script task using the "Edit Script" button or update in  "test.dtsx" file manually but it is not effect my changes in sending email. The sent email still showing old template. Please help how I can update script task.

Thank you for your help !!

[image]

Comment: Can you see your changes in the package?

Comment: Does it not change the email when you run it in the debugger?   If not, then step through the code in the debugger and watch what's going on.

Comment: Amnesh Goel - Yes I can view my changes in script file. I have open the "test.dtsx" file and edit my changes but it is not change in sent email. Actually I have change simple text in email body no more...

Comment: Tab Alleman - I have debugging my package but when it come on script task then no break point executed. Can you please tell me where I can find the script task and what is the best way to update the script task. Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your task is using an expression to populate this field.

Open the task and have a look at the expressions tab and expand the "Expressions" group, you may find that Message Source is defined here. This is often done when the developer wants to include a variable value in the message.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! But I have verified and edit my question.. there is no expression. I also notice I couldn't be able to debug my script file. It seems its executing on different location.

Comment: Apologizes, I mis-read the question and thought you were using the mail task.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes, saving the script task can be temperamental. Running a build of the script can help.

Comment: Neil - I have open the "text.dtsx" file and save my changes. I have tired to rebuild and same result..

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the script whilst the script editor is open? Rather than the entire package

Comment: Neil - You are great!!! Yes I was forget to rebuild the script editor. It is working now. Thank you...